# Dragging not working on Custom class inherited from Moviclip

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

**EDIT:** If I have a class called Items and it has a movieclip instance which is loaded from a url. The startDrag on item fails. If Items contains a movieclip which we initiate from a SWC (not load it) on Drag works fine.

*Now how to solve the issue where I have a class which has a movieClip loaded from outside.*

I have the following code:

package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

```
import lib.CustomEvents.ItemLoadCompleteEvent;
import lib.Room.Item;
import lib.Room.ItemStruct;

public class DragTest extends Sprite
{
    private var itemInstance:Item;
    public function DragTest()
    {
        var tempItemStruct:ItemStruct = new ItemStruct("test",0,0,200,250,"wall","","inventory");
        itemInstance = new Item(tempItemStruct);
        itemInstance.addEventListener(ItemLoadCompleteEvent.CONTROL_TYPE,loadComplete);

        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,mouseUp);
    }

    private function loadComplete(e:ItemLoadCompleteEvent):void
    {
        itemInstance.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,mouseDown);
        this.addChild(itemInstance);

    }

    private function mouseUp(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        itemInstance.stopDrag();
        trace("MouseUp");
    }

    private function mouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        itemInstance.startDrag();
        trace("MouseDown");

    }

}
}
```

I have used the same code with a normal clip and it works. When I use it with my own defined item it does not work. Here are the details.

itemStruct:  containing the properties of the item to be made. 
item : Loads the itemstruct defined item and puts it in a movieclip (item is inherited from movieclip)

Traces from the above code, show that only the mouseUp function works mouseDown does not work. Though the same code works fine for a simple movieclip

I have already tried

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,mouseDown);
```

EDIT: I have tried put the mouseDown on stage again if I click outside the item and drag from stage it both mouseDown and Up seem to work. But If I click on the item and drag. Still no luck. I have also added the item as movieclip on stage.

Answer (score 0):

the event is probably being dispatched from the loaded clip, not item itself. Try using the mouseChildren property to catch all events.

```
 item.mouseChildren = false;
```

Comment: I have made it work somehow, but still I need a solution for attaching the mouseDown on the parentClass of the moviclip. Still its still working on the direct movielclip itself.